# Expression must have class type vs

Tags: c++

Greetings I am getting this problem "Expression must have class type"
-the code is something like this it's made to protect constant values-

Class.h

```
Class Myclass{
    Public: My class();
    Private: 
    const int value;
};
```

Class CPP

```
Myclass::Myclass()
   :value(5)
   {}
```

Main

```
#include "Myclass.h"
#include <iostram.h>
int main()
{
    Myclass Smth();
    int five=Smth.value; // error line  
                         // Smth is underlined       
    return(0);
}
```

thanks

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and the error message in the question. The code as posted has lots of typos...

Comment: No. It is because `value` is private. Also, your code is full of syntax errors. You don't start keywords like `public` with a capital. You can't separate words like `My class`.

Comment: `Class` should be `class`, `Public` should be `public`, `My class();` should be `Myclass();` and maybe more

Comment: This is a most vexing parse. `Myclass Smth();` is a function declaration. And, of course, lots of keywords with incorrect capitalization, as everyone is pointing out.

Comment: That's not a copy of the code, the code had no syntax errors, I had tried it with public and private members as well as with const int and just int type.

Comment: "That's not a copy of the code, the code had no syntax errors"  why? We can only answer on the code you post. If your question is not about those syntax errors you should have removed them. Now it is too late, because the answers do answer your question as it stands (including the syntax errors)

Comment: Still that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: `Myclass Smth(); ` is considered as a function declaration with return value `Myclass` you need to initialize the object as `Myclass Smth;`

Answer (score 2):

You're spelling `class`, `private`, and `public` incorrectly and you can't have spaces in names:

```
Class Myclass {
    Public: My class();
    Private: 
    const int value;
};
```

should be:

```
class Myclass {
    public: Myclass();
    private: 
    const int value;
};
```

and you can't access `value` outside of the `Myclass` because it's `private`.

Comment: What is compiler interpretation of `Class` ?

Comment: A syntax error basically, the compiler will see it as an undeclared name.

Comment: But as highlighted in question it shouldn't be error for accessing member variables.  If you had noticed even `Public` and `Private` are also have first letter capitalized.

Comment: @TruthSeeker You won't have any members or anything, it won't compile. I did notice, look at my answer.

Comment: That's not a copy of the code, the code had no syntax errors, I had tried it with public and private members as well as with const int and just int type

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a `private` member. Also, this line is better to be `Myclass Smth;`.

Comment: That's not a copy of the code, the code had no syntax errors, I had tried it with public and private members as well as with const int and just int type